# Mapbox mousemove Event Listener not Disabling

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, removeeventlistener

I'm using the mousemove event listener in mapbox to be able to drag a point around the map. However, when I'm calling .off() on it, it isn't disabling. I'm doing this in Angular with Typescript.

Original Call:

```
this.map.mapInstance.on('mousemove', this.onPointMove.bind(this));
this.map.mapInstance.once('mouseup', this.onPointUp.bind(this));
```

onPointMove(e):

```
const coords = e.lngLat;

this.map.mapInstance.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'grabbing';

console.log(coords);
```

onPointUp(e):

```
this.map.mapInstance.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = '';

this.map.mapInstance.off('mousemove', this.onPointMove.bind(this));
```

After I finish dragging, the console.log still gets outputted when I move my mouse around.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you need to pass the exact same function to `off`, not a new function which does the same thing.

```js
const mousemove = this.onPointMove.bind(this);
this.map.mapInstance.on('mousemove', mousemove);

// ...

this.map.mapInstance.off('mousemove', mousemove);
```